# Is there any auto commit happens after executing stored procedures in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 tables in oracle DB. I am writing one procedure to delete some rows in all the 3 tables based on some conditions.

I have used all three delete statements one by one in the procedure. While executing the mentioned stored procedure, is there any auto-commit happening in the at the time of execution?

Otherwise, Should I need to manually code the commit at the end?

Comment: Within a PL/SQL function or procedure there is no autocommit.

Comment: I am using oracle command line. In that, I am executing the above mentioned procedure. After executing that, should I need to enter commit command manually since i am using delete statement in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no auto-commit on the database level, but the API that you use could potentially have auto-commit functionality.  [From Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:314816776423).

That said, I would like to add:

Unless you are doing an autonomous transaction, you should stay away from committing directly in the procedure: [From Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1519405621318).

Excerpt:

> I wish PLSQL didn't support commit/rollback.  I firmly believe
>   transaction control MUST be done at  the topmost, invoker level.  That
>   is the only way you can take these N stored procedures and tie  them
>   together in a transaction.

In addition, it should also be noted that for DDL (doesn't sound like you are doing any DDL in your procedure, based on your question, but just listing this as a potential gotcha), Oracle adds an implicit commit before and after the DDL.

Answer (score 5):

There's no `autocommit`, but it's possible to set commit command into stored procedure.

Example #1: `no commit`

```
create procedure my_proc as
begin
  insert into t1(col1) values(1);
end;
```

when you execute the procedure you need call `commit`

```
begin
  my_proc;
  commit;
end;
```

Example #2: `commit`

```
create procedure my_proc as
begin
  insert into t1(col1) values(1);
  commit;
end;
```

When you execute the procedure you don't nee call `commit` because procedure does this

```
begin
  my_proc;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no autocommit with in the scope of stored procedure. However if you are using SQL Plus or SQL Developer, depending on the settings autocommit is possible.

You should handle commit and rollback as part of the stored procedure code.